# Is it possible to enforce Numpy to use cutout rather than overflow when doing type conversion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, type-conversion

I have a numpy array as follow:

```
array([  46.73017823, -250.31618571, -247.44416527,   97.52841554,
       -204.92988386,  191.09452493,  103.15708521,  -86.10470495,
         46.211924  , -195.30653599,  240.44499889, -169.42729244,
        210.44996545, -182.04892973, -166.20581924, -221.11524425,
        164.79367242, -199.80888341,   94.1786936 ,   43.45477102])
```

I want to cast this array to `uint8` so that I won't have the negative values anymore. I do this using `npArr = npArr.astype(np.uint8)`. However, it seems that Numpy does not cutout when doing such conversions. Therefore, instead of getting `0` for all negative values, I am getting some positive values. Here's what I get after doing the conversion to `uint8`:

```
array([ 46,   6,   9,  97,  52, 191, 103, 170,  46,  61, 240,  87, 210,
        74,  90,  35, 164,  57,  94,  43], dtype=uint8)
```

I know I can easily get around this issue by doing `npArr[npArr < 0] = 0` but I'm afraid similar things might happen if I convert a 32-bit float array to a 16-bit array and so on. So I wonder if it would be possible to do type conversion using Numpy in a way that Numpy will use cutout rather than overflow so that I won't get weird numbers after conversion. It would also be nice if someone can propose a unified solution on how people should convert types using Numpy so that they won't encounter such issues.

Comment: I suspect you mean `cut off` or `clip` rather than `cutout`.  `npArr[npArr < 0] = 0` is the logical way of doing this.  Or `np.maximum(a, 0)`.  `dtype` conversion isn't meant for changes in values like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to do the following:

```
convtype = np.uint8
convtype_info = numpy.iinfo(convtype)
numpy.clip(npArr, convtype_info.min, convtype_info.max, npArr)
npArr = npArr.astype(convtype)
```

this uses the numpy given type-limits from [`numpy.iinfo`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) to restrict the elements to the range `[min, max]` of the specified conversion type using [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) working in-place.